# ios simulator webview throws "Timeout has occurred"

Tags: swift, angular, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration, ionic6

I'm doing a simple mobile application which embeds a `WkWebView` to display my website using `Ionic 6` + `Angular`.

I have tested my website with Chrome and Safari on Macbook, everything was fine until I opened it on my `WKWebView` control.

At first, my webview displayed successfully (as the below image)

[image]

When I clicked `Submit` button, my `Ionic 6` website would call an API Endpoint & continued download some chunks and go to the next page.

However, this is what I got after `Submit` button has been clicked:

[image]

The error message was:

```
[Error] ERROR
Object

info: {meta: null, lastValue: null, seen: 0}

message: "Timeout has occurred"

name: "TimeoutError"

stack: "@http://****/main.02dd4c6bece51f6f.js:1:175858↵@http://****/main.02dd4c6bece51f6f.js:1:43982…"
```

This is how I setup my webview:

```
 func setupWebView() {
        let url = URL(string: "http://<my-end-point>/")!
        let request: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 180)
        webView.load(request)
    
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        webView.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: listenerName)
    }
```

My question is:

- Can I increase the timeout of `WKWebView` to by pass this issue ?
- I haven't deployed my app onto physical device, is it an issue of simulator only ? or it is physical device issue also ?

Comment: This might be unrelated to WKWebView entirely.
Did you check if your website works correctly in the simulator's Safari browser?

Comment: You should be using `https` for your requests. `http` is not secure and by default iOS blocks insecure network requests. You may want to look into your App Transport Security settings. You may find this link helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/31254874/5508175

Comment: @EugenTimm, I have checked with safari, it worked, even with http or https :(

Comment: @Andrew, I tried with https also. My website has been deployed to netlify.com. I use ngrok to use its https. Everything was https, the problem still persisted :(

Comment: have you tried using a different url for a website that you know works?